# How to replace an HTML element's text with JavaScript when the element doesn't have a class?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: Wanted to change the sentence "watch yesterday's broadcast" to "watch the webinar now"]

Wanted to change the sentence "watch yesterday's broadcast" to "watch the webinar now"

Comment: Why can't it have an id or class?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). What have you tried so far?

Comment: Maybe he doesn't have control of the HTML produced? Maybe he's scraping a website and wants to transform the content in some way.

Comment: @JarneKompier because I use Clickfunnels, they don't give users the accessibility to hard code

Comment: You could try `document.querySelectorAll('[value]')` this will return an object with all the elements that have a value attribute.

Answer (score 2):

What about selecting it by using its DOM order?

```
var perent = document.querySelector("select");
var element = parent.querySelectorAll("option")[1];
element.innerHTML = "watch the webinar now";
```

This article can help: [How to get the child element of a parent using JavaScript?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-child-element-of-a-parent-using-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector` to get an specific child inside an element and change it.

### Snippet

> In this case I use `querySelector(':nth-child(2)')` to get the second child.

```js
var parent = document.querySelector(".someClassName");

console.log(
  parent.querySelector(':nth-child(2)').text
)

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  parent.querySelector(':nth-child(2)').text = 'asdasd asdasd';
})
```

```html
<button id='btn'>change</button>

<select class="someClassName">
  <option>aker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</option>
  <option>Donec semper tortor ac velit tempus,</option>
  <option>vel pellentesque lorem gravida</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Even better you can use `option:nth-child()` to exclude other elements that might be the second under their parent

Answer (score 1):

To change the text of the *second* option

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].options[1].innerHTML = "watch the webinar now";
```

If the option is not always second, you can give the option a `id` then use that in your query selector.